# Drupal 8: Custom Module Block default configuration not working

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I am learning how to create a custom module in `Drupal 8`. I am stuck in creating the default configuration for a block of the module.

The name of my module is `hello`. As required, I have created a file `hello/config/install/hello.settings.yml`. Then as required I also created the `defaultConfiguration()` method in my `HelloBlock` class.

I tried deleting the module, reinstalling it and also tried clearing the cache. But still, after I install the module and place the block, it just says `Hello !` instead of `Hello, Batman!`

Here is the required code -

**hello/config/install/hello.settings.yml**

```
hello:
  name: 'Batman'
```

**hello\src\Plugin\Block\HelloBlock.php**

Here is the defaultConfigurtion() function -

```
public function defaultConfiguration() {
   $default_config=\Drupal::config('hello.settings');
   return array(
   'name'=>$default_config->get('hello.name'),
  );
 }
```

Here is the entire HelloBlock class -

```
class HelloBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function defaultConfiguration() {
  $default_config=\Drupal::config('hello.settings');
  return array(
    'name'=>$default_config->get('hello.name'),
  );
}


//Submit the form and save the form value into block configuration
public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  parent::blockSubmit($form,$form_state);
  $values=$form_state->getValues();
  $this->configuration['hello_block_name'] = 
  $values['hello_block_name'];
}

//Add the form
public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form = parent::blockForm($form,$form_state);
  $config = $this->getConfiguration();
  $form['hello_block_name'] = array(
    '#type'=> 'textfield',
    '#title'=> 'Who',
    '#description'=>$this->t('Who do you want to say hello to?'),
    '#default_value'=>isset($config['hello_block_name'])?
    $config['hello_block_name'] : ' ',
  );
  return $form;
}

//Build the module i.e. Control the view of block
public function build() {
  $config = $this->getConfiguration();

 if (!empty($config['hello_block_name'])) {
   $name = $config['hello_block_name'];
 }
 else {
   $name = $this->t('to no one');
 }
 return array(
   '#markup' => $this->t('Hello @name!', array (
       '@name' => $name,
     )),
 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they didn't try their own tutorial, I've struggled a bit with this, but if you look at the source code of the popup, the name of the field is actually `hello_block_name` so you should have this in your `defaultConfiguration()`:

```
public function defaultConfiguration() {
  $default_config=\Drupal::config('hello.settings');
  return array(
    'hello_block_name'=>$default_config->get('hello.name'),
  );
}
```